# Given Gram matrix, find any set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given Gram matrix $G_{ij}=\left \langle e_i,e_j \right\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}41 &12 &13 \\ 12 &48  &4 \\  13& 4 & 11\end{bmatrix}$.
>
> Find any set of vectors $\left\{ e_1,e_2,e_3\right\}$ corresponding to it.

---

My attempt:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
e_{11} & e_{21} &e_{31} \\ 
e_{12} &e_{22}  &e_{32} \\ 
 e_{31}&e_{32}  &e_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}$ -three columns of the  vectors.

Then we have a  $9$ eqution system with $9$ unknown coordinates - $A^T\cdot A=G$, but it isn't linear.
May I ask if there is another method for solving this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

All Gram matrices $G$ are symmetric and positive definite. Therefore, since the $A$ matrix is also square, a Cholesky decomposition $G=LL^T$ is always possible. Then take $A=L^T$, so $A^TA=G$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's proceed inductively **in case we want to obtain an explicit solution**

(which I presume is your main intent):

$1-$Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be the canonical basis and take $e_1=\sqrt{41} v_1$ because $e_{11}=41$.

$2-$Take $e_2=\frac{12}{\sqrt{41}}v_1+a v_2$ because $e_{12}=12$.

$3-$Take $e_3=\frac{13}{\sqrt{41}}v_1+b v_2+c v_3$ because $e_{13}=13$.

$4-$Note that $e_{22}=\frac{144}{41}+a^2=48$, which gives $a$.

$5-$Note that $e_{23}=\frac{156}{41}+ab=4$, which gives $b$.

$6-$Note that $e_{33}=\frac{169}{41}+b^2+c^2=11$, which gives $c$.

Answer (score 1):

There is Lagrange's method; we begin with
$$ 41 x^2 + 48 y^2 + 11 z^2 + 8 yz + 26 zx + 24 xy $$
and find it equals 
$$ (4x+4y+3z)^2 + (3x+4y-z)^2 + (4x-4y+z)^2 $$

Unless the numbers are chosen carefully, we expect coefficients on the squares